# An exercise with prime numbers

Tags: functions, proof-verification, prime-numbers

I am trying to give a solution to the following exercise:

> Let $f$ be a function from the set of positive integers to itself such that, for every $n$, the number of positive integer divisors of $n$ is equal to $f(f(n))$. For example, $f(f(6)) = 4$ and $f(f(25)) = 3$. Prove that if $p$ is prime, then $f(p)$ is also prime.

**My try:**

If $p$ is prime, then $f(f(p)) = 2$ by definition of $f$, which means $f(f(f(p))) = f(2)$. If $f(p)$ is not prime, then either $f(p) = 1$ - i.e. $f(f(f(p))) = 1$ - or $f(2) = f(f(f(p))) > 2$ as at least $1$ and $f(p)$ divide $f(p)$. In the first case we get $f(f(p)) = 2 = f(1)$, which yields $f(2) = 1$.

I do not know how to go on from here. Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: looks good to me

Comment: Why is $f(2) = 2$?

Comment: Good point. I edit it.

Comment: Looks fine to me...though slightly confusing. Very nice.

Comment: It seems I cannot do more than this for now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any number $p$, $f(p)$ is prime if and only if $f(f(f(p)))=2$, when $p$ is prime this means that $f(p)$ is prime if and only if $f(2)=2$. But we have that $f(f(2))=2$ and this implies $f(f(f(2)))=f(2)$, so $f(2)$ equals the number of its divisors, and can only be $1$ or $2$. Therefore, in case $f(2)=1$, we would have $f(p)=1$ for every prime $p$.

But this is impossible: notice that $f(f(f(4))))=f(3)=1$, hence $f(4)$ has only one divisor, which means $f(4)=1$, implying $f(f(4))=f(1)=2$, a contradiction.

Comment: Why $f(2) = 2$ implies $f(p)$ prime?

Comment: Because then $f(f(f(p)))=2$, meaning $f(p)$ has only two divisors, i.e., it is prime.

Comment: It looks good to me.